# Kafka - The size of the current ISR Set(1) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 2 for partition __consumer_offsets-0

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two brokers running, and here is the contents of the `server.properties` file.

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka02:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/data/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=kafka01:2181,kafka02:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
delete.topic.enable=true
auto.create.topics.enable=true
log.roll.ms=604800000
default.replication.factor=2
min.insync.replicas=2
num.replica.fetchers=2
replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
zookeeper.set.acl=false
```

As you can see, the `min.insync.replicas` property is set to 2, but I keep receiving messages like below.

```
[2021-04-09 17:47:12,733] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=1] Error processing append operation on partition __consumer_offsets-3 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: The size of the current ISR Set(1) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 2 for partition __consumer_offsets-3
```

According to this message, the ISR for the topic `__consumer_offsets` is still set to 1. Here is the description result for the topic.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-222-3-44:~/kafka/bin$ ./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic __consumer_offsets
Topic: __consumer_offsets       PartitionCount: 50      ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 4    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 5    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 6    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 8    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 9    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 10   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 11   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 12   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 13   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 14   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 15   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 16   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 17   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 18   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 19   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 20   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 21   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 22   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 23   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 24   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 25   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 26   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 27   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 28   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 29   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 30   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 31   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 32   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 33   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 34   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 35   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 36   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 37   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 38   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 39   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 40   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 41   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 42   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 43   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 44   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 45   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 46   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 47   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 48   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 49   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
```

The `NotEnoughReplicasException` is probably due to the conflict between `min.insync.replicas=2` and `ISR: 1` of `__consumer_offsets`. How can I set the ISR to 2?

Comment: You may look into the broker configuration `offsets.topic.replication.factor` as this configuration declares the requirements for the internal __consumer_offsets topic..

Comment: Exactly... Seems like you might have started a Kafka cluster before modifying that property? You have `ReplicationFactor: 1` as that topics config, so the min ISR of 2 will never be reached